# Remove nonull constraint on database table with liquibase

Tags: database, liquibase

I have a table of users which was created with `nullable: false` constraint. Now I need to remove this constraint, but it seems I can only remove one constraint at a time with something like this:

```
databaseChangeLog:
  - changeSet:
      id: 1024
      author: thomas
      dropNotNullConstraint:
        tableName: sup_user
        columnName: supplier_id
        columnDataType: VARCHAR(255)
```

But I also want to remove the constraint for the column `supplier_name`. Do I just need multiple `changeSet`s or can I combine the changes within one set?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not very familiar with Liquibase 'SQL notation', but it's a good practice to make changeSets atomic. So yes, I'd say you should write a separate changeSet to drop another not null constraint.

Please note that it's also a good practice to write preConditions for the changeSets to make sure they will not fail during execution or to try to avoid that possible fail and make an appropriate action if the fail is imminent.

Answer (score 1):

the best practice is to create a new changeset for your modification if the application is in production, but if the application is in test or in development, we can change the old changeset as long as you manually delete the table that has already been created by this changeset and delete its entry in the databasechangelog table to avoid the checksum error